# Using Winscard.dll with JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

I'm trying to read out reader attributes on a Windows-PC with Java JNA using SCardGetAttrib (Winscard.dll) function but I don't know exactly how to use the JNA to get what I want.

This is the Interface:

```
public interface Winscard extends Library  {
  Winscard INSTANCE = (Winscard) Native.loadLibrary("winscard", Winscard.class);

  NativeLong sCardGetAttrib(NativeLong hCard, int dwAttrId, ByteBuffer pbAttr, IntBuffer pcbAttrLen);
```

}

I took the type signature from http://crypto-native.sourceforge.net/crypto-native-pcsc/apidocs/net/sf/crypton/scard/pcsclite/PcscliteLibrary.html#SCardGetAttrib%28com.sun.jna.NativeLong,%20int,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.IntBuffer%29 but of course this is the signature for the PcscliteLibrary. I hoped it would be similar enough to the Winscard function. So where do I get the right signature of the function?

I tried to call the function using this, just to try if it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  IntBuffer b = IntBuffer.allocate(1024);
  Winscard winscard = Winscard.INSTANCE;
  winscard.sCardGetAttrib(null, 0, null, b);
}
```

but I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'sCardGetAttrib':
```

Actually I need to use something like SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME or SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_NAME as dwAttrId.

Sorry, I have very less knowledge about this theme. Could anybody help?

Comment: Try `SCard...` instead of `sCard...`.

Comment: After that, you're going to run into problems until you understand the parameters you are supposed to be passing to the function.  You're passing a null buffer, and an uninitialized, allocated buffer of size 1024 for the buffer which is intended to hold your data buffer size.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's working and I'm able to read out the attributes. However this does only work when a card is present at the reader. I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357557/jna-and-winscard-reading-attributes-scardgetattrib-without-card. Maybe you could help me again. I'd be very glad!

Comment: For those who are interested: the problem is solved and you can find the code at the other Thread (link in the previous comment).